# Find sum of value for each ID if date between 2 dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
data={'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
      'date1':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,4),
               datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'date2':[datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,5),
               datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'score1':[5,7,3,2,9,3,8,3],
      'score2':[1,3,0,5,2,20,7,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

And dataframe df looks like this:

```
   id       date1       date2  score1  score2
0   1  2016-01-01  2016-01-05       5       1
1   1  2016-01-02  2016-01-03       7       3
2   1  2016-01-02  2016-01-05       3       0
3   1  2016-01-04  2016-01-05       2       5
4   2  2016-01-02  2016-01-04       9       2
5   2  2016-01-04  2016-01-05       3      20
6   2  2016-01-03  2016-01-04       8       7
7   2  2016-01-01  2016-01-01       3       7
```

Another dataframe UF that contains ID, usetdate

```
   id      usetdate  
0   1  2016-01-01    
1   1  2016-01-03    
2   2  2016-01-04    
3   2  2016-01-02
```

I want to find sum of score1 and score2 against each ID of UF if my date(usetdate) passed is between date1 and date2

```
   id      usetdate  score1  score2
0   1  2016-01-01      5       1
1   1  2016-01-03     17       9
2   2  2016-01-04     20       29
3   2  2016-01-02     9        2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Series` with all datetimes first by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), swap index with values in `Series` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original, last aggregate `sum`:

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.date1, r.date2)) for r in df.itertuples()])
s = pd.Series(s.index, index=s, name='usetdate')

df = df.drop(['date1','date2'],axis=1).join(s).groupby(['id','usetdate'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   id   usetdate  score1  score2
0   1 2016-01-01       5       1
1   1 2016-01-02      15       4
2   1 2016-01-03      15       4
3   1 2016-01-04      10       6
4   1 2016-01-05      10       6
5   2 2016-01-01       3       7
6   2 2016-01-02       9       2
7   2 2016-01-03      17       9
8   2 2016-01-04      20      29
9   2 2016-01-05       3      20
```

EDIT:

```
L = [(i, d, s1, s2) for i, d1, d2, s1, s2 in df.values for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2)]
df = (pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['id','usetdate','score1','score2'])
        .groupby(['id','usetdate'], as_index=False).sum())
print (df)
   id   usetdate  score1  score2
0   1 2016-01-01       5       1
1   1 2016-01-02      15       4
2   1 2016-01-03      15       4
3   1 2016-01-04      10       6
4   1 2016-01-05      10       6
5   2 2016-01-01       3       7
6   2 2016-01-02       9       2
7   2 2016-01-03      17       9
8   2 2016-01-04      20      29
9   2 2016-01-05       3      20
```

EDIT:

You can `merge` values with left join before aggregating:

```
df1['userdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['userdate'])
print (df1)
   id   userdate
0   1 2016-01-01
1   1 2016-01-03
2   2 2016-01-04
3   2 2016-01-02

L = [(i, d, s1, s2) for i, d1, d2, s1, s2 in df.values for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2)]
df = (pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['id','userdate','score1','score2'])
        .merge(df1)
        .groupby(['id','userdate'], as_index=False)
        .sum())
print (df)
   id   userdate  score1  score2
0   1 2016-01-01       5       1
1   1 2016-01-03      15       4
2   2 2016-01-02       9       2
3   2 2016-01-04      20      29
```

EDIT1:

You can filter values in list comprehension converted to tuples:

```
df1['userdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['userdate'])
print (df1)
   id   userdate
0   1 2016-01-01
1   1 2016-01-03
2   2 2016-01-04
3   2 2016-01-02

a = [tuple(x) for x in df1.values]
print (a)
[(1, Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00')), (1, Timestamp('2016-01-03 00:00:00')), 
 (2, Timestamp('2016-01-04 00:00:00')), (2, Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'))]
L = [(i, d, s1, s2) for i, d1, d2, s1, s2 in df.values 
                    for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2) 
                    if (i, d) in a]
df = (pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['id','userdate','score1','score2'])
        .groupby(['id','userdate'], as_index=False)
        .sum())
print (df)
   id   userdate  score1  score2
0   1 2016-01-01       5       1
1   1 2016-01-03      15       4
2   2 2016-01-02       9       2
3   2 2016-01-04      20      29
```

Comment: I want to avoid the join step as I have a huge (5L record) data set

Comment: @Curious - Added another solution, but here working with large data is always slow, because loops are necessary for datetimes.

Comment: Thanks! But your code adds new records in my dataset. I only want to see sum of scores for records I specified as 'usetdate' .

Comment: @Curious - Not understand, how are datetimes specified? Between `2016-01-01` and `2016-01-04` ? Can you explain more?

Comment: So basically I have two datasets. The first one contains Id, date1, date2, score1, score2. My second dataset contains some Ids and some dates (userdates) corresponding to those Ids.  So my ask is, I want to find score (total) corresponding to each userdate, Id, on the condition that date falls in a range (date1,date2)

Comment: I have also edited my question to make it more clear :)

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without merge/join ? Constraint is the length of data I am using

Comment: @Curious - First I think not possible, but I got it, here is possible filtering in list comprehension by tuples. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

data={'id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
      'date1':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,4),
               datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'date2':[datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,5),
               datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'score1':[5,7,3,2,9,3,8,3],
      'score2':[1,3,0,5,2,20,7,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

data={'id':[1,1,2,2],
      'date':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,4)]}

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

data1=[]
x=[]
def agg(df,df1):
    for i in range(1,2):
        x=list(df1.id)
        y=list(df1.date)
        data1= df[df.id==x[i]]
        data2=data1[data1.date1 > y[i]] 
        data3=data2[data1.date2 < y[i]]
        data4=data3.groupby(['id']).agg({"score1":sum})
        x.append(data4)
    return data4

agg(df,df1)
```

Please try this